# Factor $ax+by+abx+aby+abxy$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I am trying to factor the polynomial $ax+by+abx+aby+abxy\ $ but can't come up with a way to do it.

Does anyone know how to factor this?  (I know it can be taken to $ax+by+ab(x+1)(y+1)-ab\ $ but that isn't even close to factored)

Comment: [Mathematica](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/98tMbkkvyg6UaFCO0mhUjtRIQnIApFQtkJl7P///3ULijLzSgA): no way it can be factored _per se_.

Comment: It ultimately depends on what you mean by "factored". For a multivariable expression like this, [there's rarely just one justifiable "factoring,"](https://i.imgur.com/yZU0KLw.png) and whatever factoring you want usually depends on your intended use of the expression.

Comment: @PrincessEev alright, I was trying to come up with something like a product. (what resource did you use to do that factoring)

Comment: I just threw it into WolframAlpha.

Comment: PARI/GP screens it as irreducible as well.